# Fetching API data from Ember Controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am an Ember newbie and am trying to create a simple application to fetch records from an API server.

Currently I am trying to query the

```
 this.store.find('validemail',{'email':'abc.gmail.com'}).then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
  });
```

//Console log on browser

```
Class {query: Object, store: Class, manager: Class, isLoaded: true, meta: Object…}__ember1434866946710: "ember592"__ember_meta__: Object__nextSuper: undefinedcontent: (...)get content: GETTER_FUNCTION() {set content: SETTER_FUNCTION(value) {isLoaded: truemanager: Classmeta: Objectquery: Objectstore: Classtype: client@model:validemail:__proto__: Class
```

This is a lot of data but I am not able to make any sense of it,all I want is a success:true or success:method from the server API.

Here is my Model class
import DS from 'ember-data';

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  success:DS.attr('boolean'),
  message: DS.attr('string')

});
```

and the API method

```
router.get('/validemails',function(req,res){
   console.log(req.query);
   var useremail=req.query.email;
   Hiveuser.find({'useremail':useremail},function(err,findResponse){
      if(!isEmptyObject(findResponse)){

          res.send({"validemail": {success: false,'message': 'User Already Exists'}});
      }
      else{
          res.send({"validemail": {success: true,'message':''}});
      }
   });


});
```

I realize that I am doing something wrong because Ember Inspector shows 0 records for the model class.

What I don't get is logging the server response shows that the correct response is sent from the server but somehow it gets mangled into this garbled text  into the client.

Note: I did not even intend to use Ember Models for this simple use case ,but sending a jQuery GET request would require me to hardcode server IP into the controller ,hence had to go the Adapter "route"(No pun intended :) )

If there is a way I can send a JSON request from the controller which would take the server ip from the Adapter I'd very much like to know about it.

Thanks

Comment: So you did see that records were returned from the server in something like chrome inspector?

Comment: Yes Chrome inspector shows some response but I can't seem to find the json returned from the server anywhere.
`Class {query: Object, store: Class, manager: Class, isLoaded: true, meta: Object…}__ember1434866946710: "ember592"__ember_meta__: Object__nextSuper: undefinedcontent: (...)get content: GETTER_FUNCTION() {set content: SETTER_FUNCTION(value) {isLoaded: truemanager: Classmeta: Objectquery: Objectstore: Classtype: client@model:validemail:__proto__: Class`

Comment: Can you post the json returned from the server? Ember has a lot of expectations about what you send it.

Comment: `{'validemail': {success: true,'message':''}}` This is the response json sent from the server

Comment: I'm not 100% on this but I believe ember expects you to return the records as an array of objects. For example, `{"validemail": [{"success": true, "message": ""}]}`. You might also try putting your object keys (success) in quotes if adding the array alone doesn't work. What you'll want to look for is the data showing up in ember inspector. You can deal with handling the data after that.

Comment: Your `.then(function(response){ console.log(response); });` is "eating" the response. You need to return `response` from it, or do a separate `then`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, when you execute `store.find('modelName')`, Ember REST API Adapter expects an array of models in response. Then, promise of `store.find` resolves with array of objects, and you have to get first object to see if `success === true`.

```
this.store.find('validemail', {'email':'abc.gmail.com'}).then(function(validEmails){
  console.log(validEmails.get('firstObject.success')); // true || false
});
```

API method:

```
router.get('/validemails',function(req,res){
   console.log(req.query);
   var useremail=req.query.email;
   Hiveuser.find({'useremail':useremail},function(err, findResponse){
      if(!isEmptyObject(findResponse)){
        res.send({"validemails": [{success: false, 'message': 'User Already Exists'}]});
      }
      else {
        res.send({"validemails": [{success: true, 'message':''}]});
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks that and implementing a serialized for _id in json response fixed it!! :)
I've been struggling with this for too long

Answer (score 1):

The line below

```
.then(function(response) { console.log(response); })
```

is "eating" the response. You need to return `response` from it to pass it down along the promises chain and thence to Ember for it to be set as the model:

```
this.store.find('validemail',{'email':'abc.gmail.com'}).then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
    return response;
});
```

or probably better, do a separate `then`:

```
var response = this.store.find('validemail',{'email':'abc.gmail.com'}); 
response.then(function(response) { console.log(response); });
return response;
```